# Como traduzir "Membership" e "Member" em português europeu?

Tags: tradução, português-europeu

Eu estou a utilizar "Membership = Filiação" e "Member = Membro".

Exemplo:

- Membership Policy >>> Política de Filiação
- Consumer Memberships >>> Filiações de Consumidor
- Business Memberships >>> Filiações Empresariais
- Membership Benefits >>> Benefícios da Filiação
- Member >>> Membro

Vou tentar explicar o contexto. Temos 2 tipos de "filiação": Para o Consumidor e para a Empresa. Cada um tem 3 tipos: GRÁTIS, PLUS e VIP. Com cada "filiação", pode receber benefícios diferentes, e tens que fazer certas coisas para manter os benefícios da "filiação". Tens que pagar anualmente pela "filiação".

É compressível assim? Entende-se o contexto?

Comment: Olá Roberto, bem-vindo! Não é preciso "olás" e "obrigados" nas perguntas, por cá; retirei-os; editei também um pouco o título para o tentar melhorar. [Revê as alterações](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/6196/revisions) e, se não gostares delas, escolhe a tua versão e carrega no "rollback". :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98609/discussion-on-question-by-roberto-de-nobrega-como-traduzir-membership-e-membe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu diria que pode ter vários significados. Se pudesse contextualizar melhor, era mais simples.

Por exemplo, num clube de futebol pode-se traduzir *Membership* como **Associação** e *Member* como **Associado** ou **Sócio**. Neste caso nunca se diria membro para *member*. E mesmo neste caso não se usa Associação para os exemplos que deu, porque prefere-se usar o termo Sócio, por exemplo *Membership Benefits* seria traduzido para **Benefícios para Sócios**.

Já num partido político, como já vi nos comentários do Jacinto, *Membership* seria Filiação e *Member* seria Filiado.

Se por acaso estiver a fazer um site de uma equipa de futebol e usar os termos Filiação e Filiado, vai parecer no mínimo estranho. Ao ponto que muitas pessoas não vão saber que é para ser Sócio do clube. Talvez fiquem a achar que é para pertencer ao clube como atleta. Eu ficaria, pelo menos.

---

Depois do contexto dado, pelo que eu entendi não tem nada a ver com <s>**filiação**</s> ou com <s>**associação**</s> e sim com **planos**(ou pacotes) para **clientes**(ou consumidores) e **empresas**.

Então seria qualquer coisa assim, por exemplo:

Planos para Cliente

- GRÁTIS;
- PLUS;
- VIP

Planos para Empresa:

- GRÁTIS;
- PLUS;
- VIP

Resumindo:

- Membership Policy    >>> Política de adesão
- Consumer Memberships >>> Planos para Clientes
- Business Memberships >>> Planos para Empresas
- Membership Benefits  >>> Ex: Benefícios plano Grátis/PLUS/VIP
- Member               >>> Cliente/Empresa ou Membro

Comment: 1.- Cual é a diferença entre "Planos" y "Pacotes"?. 
2.- Si eu quero falhar em geral, "Benefícios de adesão" ou "Benefícios da adesão" é possível?
3.- Há uma forma de escrever "member" para fazer uma diferença entre os "Clientes/empresas" que não formam parte da adesão e os que sim?

Comment: @RobertodeNobrega 1 - Por norma usa-se "planos", mas também já vi usarem "pacotes". 2 - Sim pode usar "Beneficios de adesão". 3 - Talvez usar mesmo "membro", exemplo: membro PLUS; ou exemplo: cliente plus. Ou talvez Cliente registado. Este ponto precisa de mais um bocadinho de contexto.

Answer (score 1):

Sou brasileiro e, pelo menos aqui no Brasil, está bom da forma como colocou.

Só uma correção: o certo é "Estou certo ou errado?" e não "Estou bem ou errado?"

Comment: Obrigado. Penso que não há outra alternativa, mas vou esperar se alguém de Portugal vir isso.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugeriria "**Regras/Regulamento de Filiação**" como alternativas talvez preferíveis para "*Membership Policy*".

Já para "*Membership Benefits*" eu sugerira "**Benefícios para Membros**" (como usado, e.g., pelo [OET](https://www.oet.pt/portal/index.php/beneficios-para-membros)), até porque "Benefícios da Filiação" pode ser entendido como se referindo a benefícios advindos do ato de se filiar (e.g., primeira anuidade grátis) ao invés benefícios (ordinários) concedidos aos membro.

E uma alternativa frequente para "membro" é "**participante**".

Comment: Já escrevi o contexto. :) @stafusa